# onmouseover event in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

Do we have onmouseover event in [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=start)? That is, when the mouse is over any row in the grid.

I could not find it in the documentation.

Also, is it possible to add onmouserevent to a particular column in jqGrid?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no event in the API for this.

It might help to explain what you are trying to do - maybe there is another way...